# Look and Say Sequence - String index out of range

Tags: python

I am trying to implement the Look and Say sequence in Python and getting the error 'String index out of range'. I am just getting started with python, so if you see any other syntax errors, please point them out as well.

```
def enlighten(number):
    i=0
    Final = []
    length = len(number)
    while i < length:
            Type=number[i]
            Nt=0
            while number[i]==Type:
                    Nt+=1
                    i+=1
            Final.append(Nt)
            Final.append(Type)
            Type=None
    return Final

inpoot = str(input("Enter a number:"))
for i in inpoot:
    print(enlighten(i))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while i < length:
   # ...
   while number[i]==Type:
       # ...
       i+=1
```

`i` is incremented inside the nested loop, causing `number[i]` out of range.

A simple and direct fix is to check the value of `i` inside the nested loop:

```
while i < length:
   # ...
   while i < length and number[i]==Type:
       # ...
       i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing the inner loop's "i" past the string length, which is only one character, anyway.  Can you describe how it is you expect this routine to work?  You haven't given us any idea of what "enlighten" is supposed to accomplish as a function.

I've added some diagnostic statements to help you track the progress of your code in the future.

```
def enlighten(number):
    print "CHECK A", number
    i = 0
    Final = []
    length = len(number)
    print "length", length
    while i < length:
        Type = number[i]
        Nt = 0
        print "CHECK B", Type, i
        while number[i] == Type and i < length:
            print "CHECK C", number[i], Nt, i
            Nt += 1
            i += 1
        Final.append(Nt)
        Final.append(Type)
        Type = None
        print "CHECK D", Final
    return Final

inpoot = str(input("Enter a number:"))
print type(inpoot), inpoot
for i in inpoot:
    print(enlighten(i))
```